# How to Create a fat jar with out compiling the code

Tags: java, maven, ant, jar

I have a third party java maven project which is stuffed with errors and can not be built any more .

But luckily i could get an already created jar (of the same java code) which works fine while running with a set of dependency jar .

Now i need to build a fat jar with all the dependencies.

I have referred lots of tutorials that explain about building fat jar by compiling the main project. is there any way i can build a fat jar with out compiling the code.

Comment: you can unjar all files and create a new jar on commandline

Comment: You can try to use the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/), maybe in combination with the [maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need source code to get a jar, with a [minimal pom](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Minimal_POM) you already get an empty jar. Add the dependencies to the pom.xml and use the [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to get your fat jar. If your project has classes but not the sources and you don't need to recompile them (are you really sure?!), you can always add them to `src/main/resources`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response . actually most of the dependent jars do not have public repositories . hence i have  put the dependent  jars at src/lib and edited the pom.xml as per the  [link] (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_external_dependencies.htm) . Then extracted the class files of the project from main jar and put the class folders inside src/main/resources .  on compiling i am getting _"aws-java-sdk:aws-java-sdk:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/src/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.0.12.jar will be unresolvable by dependent project"_

Comment: I even tried using the shade plugin following the link [https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/usage.html] please correct me if  my steps are errored or doesnt make sense

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. install existing JAR in local repo using Maven `install:file-install` (see https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)
2. Add this newly installed JAR as a dependency to your project
3. Build your fat JAR (I assume you already know how to do that)